# VSTS API Refresh Token Expires

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the VSTS REST API.  I use the refresh token, as instructed, to refresh the access token.  This morning, the refresh tokens stopped working.  Do they expire?  If the access token and refresh token have both expired, how do I proceed?  I can't find anything on this.

For reference: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth#refresh-an-expired-access-token

Comment: You can check if the authorization is revoked and the expiration date from "https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/_details/security/oauth".

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT those appear to be specific to the namespace.  The tokens I'm referring to allow an application to access any namespace the user has access to.  They can be seen at https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me?mkt=en-US&campaign=o~msft~vsts~usercard under "Authorizations" on the left

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the refresh token will be expired, you need to send request to re-authorize to get access token and refresh token again (your previous steps to authorize).

The previous access token and refresh token have been expired after get new access token.

Comment: Does the user have to see the re-authorization page again and click "Accept" a second time?  Or are you storing the original authorization code and re-using that?  Thanks!

Comment: @scottndecker Based on my test, the authorization page will be came again and I need to click Accept button too.

Comment: thanks; I've implemented this and it does work.  It very sub-optimal though and I hope MS will improve it in the future.  When else in your life have you had to give access to an application a 2nd (or 3rd, or 4th) time?  If a user only logs in every couple days, they'll have to click "Accept" every single time.  That's no good.  Refresh tokens need to live for much longer (>10 days) or there needs to be a way behind the scenes to get a new refresh token without the user clicking "Accept" again.

Comment: @scottndecker As Christopher said that the refresh token expire time is one year, you can decode refresh token via this site (https://jwt.io/), the exp value is expire time. (the difference seconds between token Issue/general universal time with 1970, 1, 1), the simple code to generate seconds C# ((dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds) and convert to actual time according to that seconds (DateTime original = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            DateTime actual = original.AddSeconds(i).ToLocalTime();)

Answer (score 1):

I manage the team that implements this flow. The answer from @starain is correct and this flow is described in detail in the OAuth 2 specification. Your observation that the refresh token is invalidated so frequently @scottndecker is not consistent with the implementation. A refresh token in our system has a default lifetime of one year. The token can also be invalidated manually by users. We obviously must honor the user's right to revoke a previously granted authorization. If you want to share some more information we can certainly look into this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Appreciate you taking the time to respond.  A year expiration sounds very reasonable.  One more question: do access and refresh tokens expire when a new access or refresh token is generated?  E.g. if the system used the refresh token to get a new access token and refresh token, would that invalidate the old access and refresh tokens even if they had not yet expired?  I believe so for the access token, but not sure on refresh token

Comment: @scottndecker The refresh token has been expired too. You will get (400) Bad Request if you request a new access token with previous refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that when the auth.token expires (after one hour), the auth.refreshtoken become invalid too? What is the auth.refreshtoken purpose then? When I decode the auth.refreshtoken on jwt.io, it should expire sometime in 2020. (Now it's 2019).

While the auth.token is valid, I can refresh and get a new token. So is the idea that I should setup a job that refreshes the token within one hour?

The documentation claims:
*If a user's access token expires, you can use the refresh token acquired in the authorization flow to get a new access token. This process is similar to the original process for exchanging the authorization code for an access token and refresh token.*

Comment: Okay... it took a couple of days to figure out what is wrong... if you have an access token, that after one hour is expired... DON'T use it.. because if you do, the refresh_token will be invalid too. So do at check (use one of the libraries on jwt.io) to see if the token is invalid before using it. If it is expired, you can use the refresh_token to get a new accesstoken.