# Visual Studio OWIN OAuth provider keeps authenticating

Tags: visual-studio, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently working on a VSTS Application, but every time I try to Login using my Visual Studio account, it keeps showing the Authorization dialog again. I have to re-authorize my App every time, which keeps generating authorizations on my Visual Studio profile, where the App is registered.

[image: Authorizations]

I'm using the OwinOauthProvider for Visual Studio. 
https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/tree/master/src/Owin.Security.Providers.VisualStudio

Is there any way to configure to provider to just authorize once and use the authorization for subsequent logins? Or any other suggestions to create a single-sign on from my App and connect to the VSTS Api's?

UPDATE:

Additional links on the issue:

https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/issues/135

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/9261621-bypass-oauth-grant-step-for-previously-authorized

(vote for it if you're experiencing the same)

Comment: What's the detail workflow of your application?

Comment: It's quite easy to replicate.
I've registered my Application on app.vsaex.visualstudio.com
Created a new empty MVC project, with Individual User accounts. Added the Owin.Security.Providers.VisualStudio as the External Login Provider. And everytime I 'login' it asks to authorize my Application again. All these authorizations show up to my vsaex profile as well. 
If I'd use Facebook for example, you authorize once and it stays authorized until my access expires or gets revoked.

Comment: The actions are different for these OAuth, for VSTS OAuth, the accept is required for each external login.

Answer (score 0):

There is access token and refresh token, the access token will be expired after an hour, but the refresh token will be expired after one year.

So, you can refresh the access token according to the refresh token instead of let user to authorized again.

Based on this thread ([VSTS API Refresh Token Expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097290/vsts-api-refresh-token-expires)), Christopher said that:

> We obviously must honor the user's right to revoke a previously
>   granted authorization

Update:

I analyzed the whole workflow, that is by design, when you request the VSTS external login, the accept page is required, you can’t control it in your code or other ways.

Comment: I've read the thread, thanks. But I don't see how it's related? See my comment on first post.

Comment: @WesleyvanHeije The relationship is that you are using VSTS OAuth, the accept page is required every time when request external login.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was hoping to make better use of the refreshtoken, so I don't have to go through the accept page every time. Especially since the refreshtoken is valid. If it's not; it makes sense that I'd have to accept again, but then the authorizations shouldn't 'add up' in my profile at app.vsaex?

Comment: @WesleyvanHeije If you just need to request the resources, you can store access and refresh tokens to the database and link a local user account to that record. On the other hand, you can submit a user voice to explain your requirement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing. But I would've preferred a single sign-on experience (like the external Facebook Provider) instead of the local logins. I've checked on Uservoice and it was logged already apparently.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/9261621-bypass-oauth-grant-step-for-previously-authorized

Comment: And either way, all application authorization get added to user's profile page every time. So the user's list gets bloated quite quickly if you'd have an application that gets used on regular basis.

Comment: @WesleyvanHeije You can follow up that uservoice. On the other hand, all authorized applications should be list now for current workflow, because the refresh token still valid for previous authorized applications.